# Checking another user's mail using sudo

Tags: email, sudo

How can I check the mailbox of another user in Linux (CentOS)? Basically I want to replicate the

```
$ mail
```

command but when sudo-ed as another user.

Right now if I try to just do

```
$ sudo -u johndoe mail
```

I get

```
/var/spool/mail/jordan: Permission denied
```

Same thing if I use

```
$ sudo su johndoe
```

and then run the `mail` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo su - johndoe -c mail
```

The `-` parameter to `su` should take care of setting up the environment for `johndoe` so the right mailbox is accessed.

Comment: Explanation: Without the `-` you are not getting the target user's full environment. In particular, you aren't getting the `MAIL` variable set to his mailbox.